# How to restrict unsuitable requests using validation rules in Laravel 5.8?

Tags: php, laravel, validation, request, restriction

I have only one validation rule in my Laravel project:

```
$validator = $request->validate([
  'search' => 'nullable|max:20',
  'sortby' => 'nullable|asc|desc',
]);
```

But if I have any another variable in my Request `$_GET['email']` for example, no error returns.

How to prevent unsupported validation inputs via validation rules?

Comment: That's actually five validation rules, on two different fields, and I think you want `asc|desc` to become `in:asc,desc`.

Comment: yep, y`r right. I did it like: `function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
     if ('asc' !== $value && 'desc' !== $value) {$fail( $attribute);}
    },`

Answer (score 0):

Just ignore them. It's not uncommon for systems outside of your control to add `$_GET` parameters - any links shared on Facebook, for example, will result in a `fbclid` (Facebook click ID) parameter coming through.

As long as your code isn't set to blindly do something with any `$_GET` parameter in the request, there's no harm in having them. Have your code specifically look for and handle `search` and `sortby`.

Comment: @Vladimir Can you elaborate on why? This sounds like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Ok. I need to return an error with specific format for Mobile App developing team. Old app`s and partner`s apps are crashing when they are using unused (for now) input variables. So, if the app send unknown variable to the server, server must response with data or error, or the app will crached...

Comment: Why is the API crashing when they send these variables, though? Why can't it just return data and ignore the unused variables? You don't have to *do* anything with them, and should fix the errors, not the symptoms of it.

Comment: I can`t fix apps, i`m not iOs or Android developer. Also, we don`t have access to src code of apps. So, nobody will do it. That`s why I did it like I did on serverside.